JPA Query with Projections and Inheritance
I have a problem when I try to query and the Items inherit from each other.
My goal is that I can query with Projections and return them in a ResponseEntity and the books and movies have their own attributes in the Json created and a type attribute.
But when I for example use repository.findAll(ItemPro.class) I only the Id in the json response.
When using Dtos I can access the attributes and the right json is created.
My example classes are:
(Every shown Dto class has BO class for database)
Item class with a wrapper class for
@Getter
@Setter
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = BookDto.class, name = "book"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = MovieDto.class, name = "movie")
})
public class ItemDto implements ItemPro
{
    private Long id;

    @AllArgsConstructor
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @Setter
    @Getter
    public static class ParentDtoList
    {
        private List<ItemDto> list;
    }
}

@Getter
@Setter
public class BookDto extends ItemDto implements BookPro
{
    private String author;
}

@Getter
@Setter
public class MovieDto extends ItemDto
{
    private String director;
}


And the projections of the Dto classes
@JsonDeserialize(as = ItemDto.class)
public interface ItemPro
{
    Long getId();
}

@JsonDeserialize(as = BookDto.class)
public interface BookPro extends ItemPro
{
    String getAuthor();
}

@JsonDeserialize(as = MovieDto.class)
public interface MoviePro extends ItemPro
{
    String getDirector();
}

